# Kill unfinished SQL commited query with psycopg2 when InterruptionKey

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I use a Python script that runs various SQL auto committed queries over a AWS Redshift database using psycopg2 library. The script is manually executed from my local workstation. The flow is the following:

- Create a database connection with psycopg2.connect()
- Execute auto-committed queries over database with execute()
- Close connection.

For various reasons, the database can be unavailable (network issue, many queries already running...) and it is better to stop the Python script. At this point, I then kill the already committed (and unfinished) queries through a SQL client (SQL workbench) by retrieving the pid associated to those queries. I would like to automate the last step directly in the Python script when user stops it (ctrl+c). The flow would be:

- Create a database connection with psycopg2.connect()
- Execute auto-committed queries over database with execute()
- Store the current PID associated to the query using info.backend_pid Connection attribute
- If InterruptionKey exception is received, kill the running query using the previously stored PID
- Close connection.

I did some test on a Notebook to check if I could retrieve the back_pid information:

```py
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
session = psycopg2.connect(
    connection_factory=LoggingConnection,
        host=host,
        port=port,
        dbname=database,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        sslmode="require",
)
session.initialize(log)
session.set_session(autocommit=True)

query = """
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION janky_sleep (x float) RETURNS bool IMMUTABLE as $$
    from time import sleep
    sleep(x)
    return True
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
"""

cur = session.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
cur.execute("select janky_sleep(60.0)")
```

I used a sleep function to replicate the behaviour of a query that would take 60s to finish.
When getting the backend_pid as following:

`session.info.backend_pid`

Issue is that session object is already in use by the execute() method (running the query) and the backend_pid information is only resulting when session is free, i.e when the query has finished.

I thought of spinning a concurrent Python process that would monitor the parent one. Once the parent process is stopped, the child would get the backend_pid through a second database connection and then run the kill query. However this approach seems overkill.

What would be the correct way to handle this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the resource found from the documentation:
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-interrupt-query. It enables Psycopg2 to get SIGINT signal and killed subsequent queries.

```
>>> psycopg2.extensions.set_wait_callback(psycopg2.extras.wait_select)
>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect('')
>>> cur = cnn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select pg_sleep(10)")
^C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  QueryCanceledError: canceling statement due to user request

>>> cnn.rollback()
>>> # You can use the connection and cursor again from here
```